# Meteor + Semantic React

Tags: reactjs, meteor, semantic-ui

### LAST EDIT :

never use npm raw command in meteor. always meteor npm. That is the reason why everything broke.

AND do upgrade step by step , version to the nearest version.

I think that's all that causes this headache.

Everything works now.

Thanks !

### EDIT :

---

After trying all the steps ahead ... I remove jquery / less and semantic:ui from meteor

```
meteor remove semantic:ui
meteor remove jquery less  
meteor npm uninstall semantic-ui semantic-ui-css
```

added

```
meteor npm install @craco/craco @semantic-ui-react/craco-less --save-dev
meteor npm install semantic-ui-less --save
meteor npm install --save react react-dom semantic-ui-react
```

launch meteor

but the react-semantic-ui css files are not there

and :

```
meteor npm install
```

returns

```
npm WARN @craco/craco@6.4.3 requires a peer of react-scripts@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @semantic-ui-react/craco-less@2.0.2 requires a peer of react-scripts@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN cosmiconfig-typescript-loader@1.0.5 requires a peer of @types/node@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN cosmiconfig-typescript-loader@1.0.5 requires a peer of cosmiconfig@>=7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN cosmiconfig-typescript-loader@1.0.5 requires a peer of typescript@>=3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN craco-less@2.0.0 requires a peer of react-scripts@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN less-loader@7.3.0 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ts-node@10.5.0 requires a peer of @types/node@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ts-node@10.5.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

---

### ORIGINAL QUESTION

I tried many things to make it work together but I am always stuck either with the

```
Error evaluating function `unit`: the first argument to unit must be a number. Have you forgotten parenthesis?
```

(I manually add prenthesis -> fixed, but it should work out of the box...)

then after

```
   While processing files with less (for target web.browser.legacy):
   client/lib/semantic-ui/definitions/globals/site.import.less:29:
   variable @googleProtocol is undefined
   error: variable @googleProtocol is undefined
```

Has someone there a "from scratch" method to create a Meteor project with semantic-ui working, please ?

Thanks

Here is all the steps (extended version) I have been through...

```
meteor create test
cd test
meteor add semantic:ui
meteor remove standard-minifier-css
meteor add less juliancwirko:postcss
```

added to package.json

```
{ "devDependencies": { "autoprefixer": "^6.3.1" }, "postcss": { "plugins": { "autoprefixer": {"browsers": ["last 2 versions"]} } } }
```

then execute

```
meteor npm install

meteor npm install semantic-ui-react semantic-ui-css
```

Test the display by adding a buttons in App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Hello } from './Hello.jsx';
import { Info } from './Info.jsx';
import {Button} from "semantic-ui-react";

export const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
      <Button primary>Primary</Button>
      <Button secondary>Secondary</Button>
    <Hello/>
    <Info/>
  </div>
);
```

then executing

```
meteor
```

but css not applied ...

Read https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Meteor and added

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.1",
    "postcss": "^6.0.22",
    "postcss-load-config": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {"browsers": ["last 2 versions"]}
    }
  }
}
```

then delete .custom.semantic.json

```
meteor npm install
```

set

```
"basic": true,
```

in  custom.semantic.json

and again

```
meteor
```

still no semantic-ui-react in the display

semantic css is not in the browser inspector :/

```
meteor add less jquery
```

then again

```
meteor
```

HERE IS THE FIRST ERROR :

```
While processing files with less (for target web.browser):
client/lib/semantic-ui/themes/default/globals/site.variables.import.less:412:19: 
Error evaluating function `unit`: the first argument to unit must be a number. Have you forgotten parenthesis?
error: Error evaluating function `unit`: the first argument to unit must be a number. Have you forgotten parenthesis?
```

let's fix it manually... by adding parenthesis...

```
@mini            : unit( (round(@miniSize * @emSize) / @emSize), rem);
@tiny            : unit( (round(@tinySize * @emSize) / @emSize), rem);
@small           : unit( (round(@smallSize * @emSize) / @emSize), rem);
@medium          : unit( (round(@mediumSize * @emSize) / @emSize), rem);
@large           : unit( (round(@largeSize * @emSize) / @emSize), rem);
@big             : unit( (round(@bigSize * @emSize) / @emSize), rem);
@huge            : unit( (round(@hugeSize * @emSize) / @emSize), rem);
@massive         : unit( (round(@massiveSize * @emSize) / @emSize), rem);

/* em */
@relativeMini    : unit( (round(@miniSize * @emSize) / @emSize), em);
@relativeTiny    : unit( (round(@tinySize * @emSize) / @emSize), em);
@relativeSmall   : unit( (round(@smallSize * @emSize) / @emSize), em);
@relativeMedium  : unit( (round(@mediumSize * @emSize) / @emSize), em);
@relativeLarge   : unit( (round(@largeSize * @emSize) / @emSize), em);
@relativeBig     : unit( (round(@bigSize * @emSize) / @emSize), em);
@relativeHuge    : unit( (round(@hugeSize * @emSize) / @emSize), em);
@relativeMassive : unit( (round(@massiveSize * @emSize) / @emSize), em);

/* rem */
@absoluteMini    : unit( (round(@miniSize * @emSize) / @emSize), rem);
@absoluteTiny    : unit( (round(@tinySize * @emSize) / @emSize), rem);
@absoluteSmall   : unit( (round(@smallSize * @emSize) / @emSize), rem);
@absoluteMedium  : unit( (round(@mediumSize * @emSize) / @emSize), rem);
@absoluteLarge   : unit( (round(@largeSize * @emSize) / @emSize), rem);
@absoluteBig     : unit( (round(@bigSize * @emSize) / @emSize), rem);
@absoluteHuge    : unit( (round(@hugeSize * @emSize) / @emSize), rem);
@absoluteMassive : unit( (round(@massiveSize * @emSize) / @emSize), rem);
```

next try

```
meteor
```

but

```
client/lib/semantic-ui/definitions/globals/site.import.less:29: variable @googleProtocol is undefined
```

error: variable @googleProtocol is undefined

lets modify it manually... and retry... but :

```
client/lib/semantic-ui/definitions/globals/site.import.less:29: variable @googleFontRequest is undefined
error: variable @googleFontRequest is undefined
```

There must be something to do, I am getting crazy or ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you add the steps you followed to set it up in first place?

Comment: Done ! In the most detailed way I could

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have created a bit of a mess for yourself. I was able to create a simple meteor app using semantic-ui-react as follows:

```
meteor create mySemanticTest
cd mySemanticTest
meteor npm install --save react react-dom semantic-ui-react semantic-ui-css
meteor
```

Then I edited `App.jsx` to be:

```js
import React from 'react';

import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

    <Button>This works</Button>
  </div>
);
```

And it all worked and looked right:

[image]

Comment: Sure, but , for e.g. , I need to define @primarycolor to slightly customize  the UI . I should thent follow : https://react.semantic-ui.com/theming but the problems of peer dependencies is unsolvable...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample system using Meteor 2.6 and Semantic UI React:

https://ics-software-engineering.github.io/meteor-application-template-react/